# How to get cursor on edit text above sdk 2.3 version on android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-2.2-froyo, android-cursor

i am doing dial pad as native dial pad on the android phones. instead of soft keyboard i have given buttons(1,2,.....*,#). that is why i need cursor visibility and soft key board hide.

In my app i have created my own dial pad with an edit text for displaying inputs and buttons for press numbers.  i have hidden the soft key board for the edittext with the following option

`dialText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);`

i am running the code on 2.3.x and its below version it works file with the dial edittext **shown the cursor on the edittext**. But if run the above code on **sdk version 4.0 its does not show the cursor**. my problem is **i need to show the cursor on edittext for all android version device**. how to do that? please help me.

To hide soft key board i am using:

```
dialText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);  // hide soft key board
```

my edit text xml:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/dialText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: What is your target SDK version?

Comment: i am using minSdkVersion = 6. my aim is it should be run on 2.0 and higher version. is it need to include  target sdk?

Comment: Do you want keyboard open when your activity launch with cursor or you want only cursor ?

Comment: i do not want to open keyboard for edittext. i need only cursor visible on edittext.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:cursorVisible="true"
```

I think thats what your looking for!

Comment: its not show the cursor by using android:cursorVisible="true".

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide your keyboard using this in onCreate() Method.

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Try this code.

```
yourEditTextHere.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {

                InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                // NOTE: In the author's example, he uses an identifier
                // called searchBar. If setting this code on your EditText
                // then use v.getWindowToken() as a reference to your 
                // EditText is passed into this callback as a TextView

                in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditTextHere
                        .getApplicationWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
               // Must return true here to consume event
               return true;

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks it shows cursor but i show the keyboard when i touch edittext. how to hide keyboard?

Comment: The given code shows the cursor but it is show the keyboard when i touch edittext.how to hide soft keyboard?

Comment: i am doing dial pad as native dial pad on the android phones. instead of soft keyboard i have given buttons(1,2,.....*,#). that is why i need cursor visibility and soft key board hide. please help me.

Comment: @ Chirag Raval i was in launch so that i cannot see your answer. i will tell you soon. Thanks

Comment: @ Chirag Raval, it will show the cursor and keyboard when i press edit text in all the version(Not only 4.0).